# How does Selenium work when used with Behat and Mink?

Tags: php, selenium, behat, mink

I have a task of running tests to a Drupal 8 website.

I have a linux box.

I have successfully configured Behat + Mink.
My tests runs OK when I'm using the default `goutte` in `behat.yml`. But when I add `@javascript` so it runs with `selenium2`, it takes too long to run (up to 25 minutes for a login test).

So I read the docs to see if I did something wrong but can't understand how it works.

I have installed Selenium for Python3 and I can do a very simple `get` and assert of a webpage, and it is supposed to use Firefox in `headless` mode, it runs somewhat fast (less than one minute), so I don't know what could be wrong in my PHP setup, using `composer`.

The question is, do I need the `Selenium Server` all tutorials talk about? (those tutorials are aged). In the Selenium docs it says that `Selenium Server` is optional and I only need this if doing `Non-remote`. What would be this? Does `Non-remote` means that it is not meant to be run in a specialized server? I only need to run my tests in the machine hosting the app.

Also, why could it be taking so much to run a simple test? What logs can I look at?

Answer (score 0):

You need `selenium server` + `driver` for specific browser for when you are running on local pc.
You need a selenium server running, so you need to start one(local/non-remote) or point to a machine that has selenium server(remote) for example when using services la BrowserStack or SauceLabs.

`@javascript` is so that he knows to start a driver with JS enabled.

If it take so much time to run a login test then you are doing something wrong, maybe you have some fixed waits or other conditions that are never true and they run until timeout.

Run Behat with `-vvv` flag, this is to increase the details of the logs.
Debug step by step and see where the issues is, try on your local pc first.

You should check for Behat tutorials, different frameworks are handling things differently, some you need only the driver, some both driver and the selenium server and some none of them because they have scripts to download and start the server automatically.

Also check for some best practices if you are new to automation.

Other related question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273927/increase-behat-performance-with-drush-driver/39309725#39309725).

For starting selenium check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468600/how-to-run-tests-in-behat-on-firefox-48-0-using-selenium-stand-alone-server/39530702#39530702).